# no input file specified on Synology DSM 5.0

Tags: php, synology

I just upgraded Synology dsm 4 to 5 and when I'm trying to access a php file, the server returns `No input file specified`.

I don't have any .htaccess files for now, which is the most common issue related to this message...

Comment: Cool, so what's the question?

Comment: How can I have my php file correctly without this error ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found the solution...

I'm trying to execute my php file in ssh live "php /volume1/web/index.php"

And I was an error with open_basedir

In the config of php in the panel, I had /volume1/web/: in the open_basedir.

So the line by default is : /var/services/tmp:

And you need to have /var/services/tmp:/volume1/web/:

Comment: Thanks. I installed NextCloud on my Synology NAS and by default when you create a new PHP profile, the custom `open_basedir` is empty and I only specified the path to the nextcloud folder.
I added the two default paths (which can be found in the default PHP profile) before it (don't forget to separate each path with `:`) and it worked.